# cordova your apk has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities

Tags: android, cordova, security, android-security

I have uploaded cordova app to playstore. But google reject app `your apk has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities`

I have cordova installed version 6.2.0.

I checked PLATFORM_VERSION in cordova.js it is

`var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '5.1.1';`

I checked properly there no any old cordova.js file with old version.

This is the plugin config which i am using

```
"cordova-plugin-battery-status": "1.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-contacts": "2.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-device-motion": "1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "1.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-dialogs": "1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-file": "4.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.5.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-globalization": "1.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.4.0",
"cordova-plugin-media": "2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "1.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "4.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.1.1"
```

I am trying since two days and check almost all related stackoverflow post but still not get resolved.

Anyone have idea why my app is rejecting?

Comment: What is the package name of the app? Also, you need to check the java files, not just the js.

Comment: @Divyesh : Did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: yes i have old cordova.js file in css folder, it causing issue.
check your www folder it must have old cordova.js file somewhere.